# Tkinter - Python crashes when I try to use a scrollbar attached to a listbox

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I can post the error log that comes up but it's absolutely massive.
The code that I have done wrong is:
    self.topFrame = Frame(self.master)
    self.topFrame.pack()

```
self.scrollGameBoardY = Scrollbar(self.topFrame)
self.scrollGameBoardX = Scrollbar(self.topFrame, orient=HORIZONTAL)
self.scrollGameBoardY.grid(row=1,column=0)
self.scrollGameBoardX.grid(row=0,column=1)
self.gameBoard = Listbox(self.topFrame,xscrollcommand=self.scrollGameBoardX.set,yscrollcommand=self.scrollGameBoardY.set,width=80,height=40)

self.scrollGameBoardX.config(command=self.gameBoard.xview())
self.scrollGameBoardY.config(command=self.gameBoard.yview())
self.gameBoard.grid(row=0,column=0)
```

The scrollbars are just not appearing, and clicking on them causes python (on mac it shows an error message that 'python has crashed etc')

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException"
```

Is the error that comes up in the console.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the lines:

```
self.scrollGameBoardX.config(command=self.gameBoard.xview())
self.scrollGameBoardY.config(command=self.gameBoard.yview())
```

Note the extra pair of parentheses on each line.  Instead of passing a *reference to* the Listbox's scrolling methods, you are passing the *result of calling those methods*.  That result is probably **None**, and in any case is not a valid command for the scrollbars to invoke.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I can't believe I missed this! However, this works to stop the error that happens when you click on the scrollbars but the scrollbars still look 'disabled/inactive' if that makes sense? How would I go about trying to fix this?

Comment: Do you actually have enough contents in the Listbox to be scrollable?  The scrollbars will disable themselves if they have nothing to do.

Comment: [Yeah, heres a gif showing it](https://gyazo.com/92d47c7b3a2e529177a8218ad9a6b315) but it's not allowing me to scroll with the scrollbars

Comment: That looks like the behavior of scrollbars attached to a Canvas with no scrollregion set.  I think it's time for you to post a new question, including minimal, runnable code to exhibit this new problem.

Comment: I would post the full code, but theres about 400 lines and only 20 of them really matter for this question but all of the code needs to be here for it to work. Sorry I'm new to StackOverflow and the whole system.